# Drupal 7 REST services - Suppress API output of NULL

Tags: 7, services

I've an API service callback function which ties up with its own module template to give an HTML output.
As per my understanding, default content type of API output is `application/json`, so I had to override it manually to `text/html`.

However, I'm still getting a `null` output always no matter whatever I try. Can someone please help me suppress this unwanted `null` output?

#### custom_module.module

```
function api_callback_function($a) {
  if (!headers_sent()) {
    drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  }
  print theme('custom_template_name_alias', array(
    'b' => $a
  ));
  return;
}

function custom_module_theme() {
  $themes = array(
    'custom_template_name_alias' => array(
      'template' => 'something-only', // name of template file, sans file extension
      'variables' => array(
        'b' => NULL
      ),
    )
  );
  return $themes;
}
```

#### something-only.tpl.php

```
<?php
$c = $variables['b'];
$path = drupal_get_path('module', 'custom_module');
global $base_url;
?>
<!doctype html><html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- HEAD related HTML code comes here -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Current value of variable 'b' = <?php echo $c; ?></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Output

> [image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning null from the callback, so it makes sense that it's printing null.

Remove the return, or return the themed string instead.

The former is probably safest, as you can be sure the default theme wrappers for the page won't be invoked.

Comment: I've tried by removing `return` statement, but in vain. So I've just kept it as is.    
Also if I return the themed string, then my HTML output will always be twice because the `custom_module_theme()` will get called twice - once when the API is manually called, and another when the module theme gets invoked.    
So we will need some other option to try.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - if you want your theme function to be executed once, just make sure you call it once, not twice.

Comment: Agreed, and that's the reason I'm printing the themed string, instead of returning it. I'm open to all suggestions if you can help me link up my module HTML template with the API callback function - I may even have to change the API service parameters used.

Comment: Sorry you've lost me. Is there more context that's missing from the question perhaps?

Comment: Okay, let's start afresh. I know the above process to be the only way to print an HTML output from an API call. And to not print the HTML twice, I've used `print theme` statement (instead of `return theme` statement) in the `api_callback_function`. I may be wrong about this process, but it's the only way that's working for me now. So please feel free to correct me on this overall process of printing HTML from an API call.

Comment: What do you mean by "API call" in this context? From a Drupal perspective, how is an "API call" different from a standard request? Or is your point that that process is transparent to you and encapsulated by the rest API module? I ask because in Drupal you either print the content from a page callback if you don't want the theme wrappers, or you return it if you do. You never return null. But the rest API module may override the page delivery callback and change something in that

Comment: Yes, it's encapsulated by the REST Services API module.

Comment: Oh ok, I'm not familiar with it. Check the hook_menu implementations in that module and see what they're doing, that'll be the key. Also check the .api.php file if here is one, as the module will probably provide a "proper" method for providing new content types

Comment: Okay, I appreciate your efforts, Clive! I earlier tried `hook_menu()` but it was futile for me. And I can't use the `.api.php` page, since I won't have any new content types at my disposal.

Comment: I meant content types as in JSON/HTML/xml/etc, it's an ambiguous topic ;) I'll try to take a look a bit later when I have some time

Comment: Happy New Year! Let's close this one and begin the new year on a positive note! Currently, I'm doing the following:-

`print theme('custom_template_name_alias', array(
    'b' => $a
  ));
 exit();`
So replacing the `return` statement with `die` or `exit` worked for me perfectly. Let me know if you've any concerns. Thank you for all the initial help!